# ImportError: cannot import name types

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying the app I cloned from following Github.

https://github.com/sfujiwara/qa-system-sample.git
(This app uses python flask, Google Natural Language API and so on.)

But, I cannot run this on Google App Engine.Following Error occurs.

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name types
at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/b~qa-system-sample2/20171223t122211.406411375873194303/lib/google/cloud/language_v1/__init__.py:17)
at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/b~qa-system-sample2/20171223t122211.406411375873194303/lib/google/cloud/language.py:17)
at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/b~qa-system-sample2/20171223t122211.406411375873194303/factoid.py:5)
at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/b~qa-system-sample2/20171223t122211.406411375873194303/main.py:9)
at LoadObject (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:85)
at _LoadHandler (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:299)
at Handle (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:240)
```

This occurs at `from google.cloud.language_v1 import types`in lib/google/cloud/language_v1/_ _init__.py.
 Although, There is types.py in /lib/google/cloud/language_v1.

I'm a beginner of python, so I couldn't find out a reason of this error.Please tell me the way to resolve this error.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I added enum into the library. It fixes this issue (although another import issue occurred)

```
libraries:
- name: enum
  version: latest
```